# How to enable Dark mode for PdfRenderer

Tags: android, pdfrenderer, android-dark-theme

I am using `PdfRenderer` to open a PDF file in Android Application. If the dark theme is enabled the text is black and the background is also black, so it looks like blank black screen. Can I change the color of the text while rendering it in `PdfRendere.Page`?

```
    private void showPage(int index) {
    if (pdfRenderer.getPageCount() <= index) {
        return;
    }
    if (null != currentPage) {
        currentPage.close();
    }
    currentPage = pdfRenderer.openPage(index);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(currentPage.getWidth(), currentPage.getHeight(),
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    currentPage.render(bitmap, null, null, PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY);
    imageViewPdf.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    }
```

Comment: Where is code ??

Comment: added code, it's usual PdfRenderer code.

Answer (score 1):

Well Not sure if a right answer but I transform the bitmap as a negative in photography not sure if is efficient enough but it works for me:

first, you have to render the bitmap with the pageRenderer:

```
var currentPage: PdfRenderer.Page = pdfRenderer.openPage(position)
currentPage?.render(bitmap, null, null, PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_PRINT)

val nightModeFlags = parent.context.resources?.configuration?.uiMode?.and(Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK)
    darkThemeEnabled = Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES == nightModeFlags

if (darkThemeEnabled) {
    bitmap = invert(bitmap)
}
```

and this is the code that makes the negative of the bitmap

```
private fun invert(original: Bitmap): Bitmap? {
    val inversion = original.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true)

    val width = inversion.width
    val height = inversion.height
    val pixels = width * height

    val pixel = IntArray(pixels)
    inversion.getPixels(pixel, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height)

    for (i in 0 until pixels) pixel[i] = pixel[i] xor RGB_MASK
    inversion.setPixels(pixel, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height)

    return inversion
}
```

hope will help you.
I have to clarify that only worked for text, if you have an image in the pdf it will show in negative.